# what is efficient and best way to achieve Session Management in Spring boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

i have requirement to develop an application. where need to implement Session management (spring boot).but after browsing i got to  know there are lot of ways where we can achieve this(Cookies,Hidden form field,URL Rewriting,HTTP Session). but now i am totally confused after getting this many option.

Comment: We'd love to help you, but your question seems very unclear and lacking detail. Could you provide a some more details?

Comment: I am guessing that @RDA wants to know which session management technique is currently most popular for Spring Boot eco-system (Ready solutions not custom). I understand that maybe questions like these are too broad and stack overflow is more about asking specific problems. Is there a stack exchange site that is more appropriate to ask such questions, cause even I have this same question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad since its not really clear what you're asking. Are you about to start implementation of your very own custom mechanism of session management? Are you looking for ready solutions that are integrated with spring boot eco-system?

Do you experience any concrete difficulties in implementation of some concrete technicality?

In general you can take a look at [spring session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/) project. It is about managing session information. You can keep the actual session information in Redis, which is supported of course.